# NSTextView's insertText method is deprecated in OS X v10.11. What is the replacement?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

I saw in the AppKit API Reference that the `insertText` method is deprecated in OS X v10.11. What am I supposed to use as a replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation says

> ```
> - (void)insertText:(id)aString
> ```
>
> This method is the means by which text typed by the user enters an `NSTextView`. See the `NSInputManager` class and `NSTextInput` protocol specifications for more information.
>   ...

In `NSTextInput` there is a note:

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> `NSTextInput` protocol is slated for deprecation. Please use `NSTextInputClient` protocol, introduced in OS X v10.5, as described in `NSTextInputClient Protocol Reference`.

In `NSTextInputClient` protocol there is a method

```
- (void)insertText:(id)aString
  replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange
```

This seems to be the appropriate replacement

Comment: Thanks. This seems like an appropriate replacement, although it needs some more code to figure out the selection range or insertion point.

Comment: I do believe this one `-(NSRange)selectedRange` is appropriate

Comment: As a related side-question, how would I proceed for a `NSTextField` ? This class doesn't conform to `NSTextInputClient`.

Comment: As far as I know `NSTextField` doesn't conform to `NSTextInput` either

Comment: With an `NSTextField` you would need to work with the field editor of the textfield, which is an `NSTextView`.

Comment: На какую функцию заменить, это итак знает каждый, Xcode об этом сообщает. А вот ответ без примера, есть нехорошо. Ваш ответ считаю бесполезным.

Comment: @iSavaDevRU First of all please write in English. Secondly the question is just *"What is the replacement?"* and it is not mentioning the used language. So you can't say the answer is not useful.

Comment: @ iSavaDevRU Sorry, I don't speak Russian. I pasted the other comment into google translate to be polite.

Comment: @vadian, я очень редко тут пишу, но иногда не могу пройти мимо. Реально ваш ответ людям не помогает. Он не заслужил звание лучший ответ. Люди были бы рады, если бы вы ответили более полно. И мне не пришлось бы лишний раз бить по клавишам. Думаю и другим людям тоже. А то, что пользователь не указал язык программирования, никакой роли не играет, данный метод устарел и для Objective C и для Swift. И конвертировать метод не проблема с любого языка, был бы пример. Удачи.

Comment: @vadian, I understand. I hope I did not offend you. I just want the answers to be more extensive and useful. Good luck to you!

Comment: @iSavaDevRU No offense taken. But please consider that your answer is actually not useful, too. `insertText:replacementRange` is not a class method  Your code won't compile

Comment: @vadian, This is called nitpicking :) This is the Instance Method. Is it important?) My answer works, does not it? And it works correctly.)

Comment: @vadian, Your code won't compile... Is working! Check it out! :)
At me all works and it has been checked up step by step. Screenshot I will not apply. I laid out what I myself did now.

Comment: @iSavaDevRU Yes, it's nitpicking and yes, it's important. `[NSTextView insertText...` implies a method called on the class. Naive beginners would be confused using the code...

Comment: @vadian, I replaced the name object. But believe me, beginners study this moment in the first place. Whatever it is written, they can not help it, if that .. :)) Of course, they should know that the name needs to be replaced with its own. They should understand that this is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Old method

```
- (void)insertText:(id)aString
```

New method

```
- (void)insertText:(id)aString replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange
```

Using the new insertText method in practice

```
// Start String: abcdef

// Result: a++bcdef
[NSTextView insertText:@"++" replacementRange:NSMakeRange(1, 0)];

// Result: a++def
[NSTextView insertText:@"++" replacementRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)];

// Result: a++f
[NSTextView insertText:@"++" replacementRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)];
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you are pasting text to the NSTextView, Please change to use this:

```
pasteAsPlainText:
```

Apple document states it in this way

Discussion
This method behaves analogously to insertText: