# NSTextField insertText method is deprecated, what is the replacement?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a NSTextField where I would like to enter text at the insertion point. I have a code that don't generate errors:

```
    let str = "Abc" 
    myTextField.insertText(str)
```

[edit]
When, in the field there is 123|45 (the "|" represents the text insertion point), the output should be 123Abc|45.

Unfortunately don't work because it's deprecated. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449174-inserttext). What is the replacement?

Please note that this question is for NSTextField not NSTextView, which has a question here: [NSTextView's insertText method is deprecated in OS X v10.11. What is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787814/nstextviews-inserttext-method-is-deprecated-in-os-x-v10-11-what-is-the-replace)

Comment: Why don't you read comments posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787814/nstextviews-inserttext-method-is-deprecated-in-os-x-v10-11-what-is-the-replace ?

Comment: Hi El Tomato, actually I read the comment by bhaller: "With an NSTextField you would need to work with the field editor of the textfield, which is an NSTextView" But to be honest I don't understand it.

Comment: @Cue , what is the the expected output do you need `insertText` when myTextField already has `44` ?

Comment: Hi RAJAMOHAN-S, when the i-beam is between 4 and 4, the output should be 4Abc|4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the field editor for the window that the text field is in, then use `insertText(_:, replacementRange:)` on that:

```
let textfield = NSTextField()...
if let fieldEditor = textfield.window?.fieldEditor(false, for: textfield) as? NSTextView {
    fieldEditor.insertText("abc", replacementRange: fieldEditor.selectedRange())
}
```

To clarify: this requires that the text field has input focus. If some other field has input focus the field editor will insert text there instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your textField has focus (is first responder) then any responder method like insertText: or inserText:replacementRange: will do the job. Problem is when you want to make the textField first responder (it will lose/reset the selectionRange).

```
func appendText(_ text: String, for textField: NSTextField) {
    makeFirstResponder(textField)
    if let fieldEditor = (textField.currentEditor() as? NSTextInputClient) {
        fieldEditor.insertText(text, replacementRange: fieldEditor.selectedRange())
    }
}

func makeFirstResponder(_ textField: NSTextField) {
    if textField.window?.firstResponder != textField.currentEditor() {
        textField.window?.makeFirstResponder(textField)
        if let length = textField.currentEditor()?.string.count {
            textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(length, 0)
        }
    }
}
```